# mongooes try to npm install mongooes

Tags: node.js, mongodb

PS E:\Node Js> npm install mongooes
npm ERR! code E404
npm ERR! 404 Not Found - GET https://registry.npmjs.org/mongooes - Not found
npm ERR! 404
npm ERR! 404  'mongooes@*' is not in this registry.
npm ERR! 404
npm ERR! 404 Note that you can also install from a
npm ERR! 404 tarball, folder, http url, or git url.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\NITISH\AppData\Local\npm-cache_logs\2022-09-20T06_30_10_137Z-debug-0.log

Comment: It's not found because you didn't spell it right. It's `mongoose`.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a mistake in the spelling of the package
It's **mongoose** not **mongooes**

Run *npm i mongoose* instead